# Power Query - Multi Level Parent Child

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a list/table with two columns, parent and child

```
Parent  Child
A   AA
AA  ASF
AA  AD
ASF KI
A   DD
W   FG
```

From this table I need to determine how many levels there are per item up and how many down. Furthermore, I also need to represent the connection up in this form:
Article|Article|Article

In the end, I would get a table out like this:

```
Parent  Child   Level Up    Level Down  String
A   AA  1   3   AA|A
AA  ASF 2   2   ASF|AA|A
AA  AD  2   2   AD|AA|A
ASF KI  3   1   KI|ASF|AA|A
A   DD  1   1   DD|A
W   FG  1   1   FG|W
```

How would you do this in Power Query?
It inelegant solution would probably be via n-Joins. But I don't know n, so the number.

Comment: Please can you clarify your desired result in row 3 of lvel down?

Comment: And I'd like to learn how you got 1 for level down on the AA/AD row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on JvdV, all in one, no other queries needed, and added the LevelDowns (if thats what you wanted)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ParentList=Source[Parent],
ChildList=Source[Child],

findparents = (x as text)=>
    let a= if List.PositionOf(ChildList, Text.AfterDelimiter(x, "|", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}))<0
    then x
    else @findparents(x & "|" & ParentList{List.PositionOf(ChildList, Text.AfterDelimiter(x, "|", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}))})
    in a,

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "LevelUp", each findparents([Child]&"|"&[Parent])),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom","LevelDown",(x)=>
    let a=  Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each  Text.Contains([LevelUp],x[Child])),
    b = Table.AddColumn(a,"Snip",(y)=> Text.Combine(List.Reverse(Text.Split(Text.BeforeDelimiter(y[LevelUp],x[Child])&x[Child],"|")),"|")),
    c= Table.AddColumn(b, "Count", (z)=>  List.Count(Text.Split(z[Snip],"|")))
    in Table.Sort(c,{{"Count", Order.Descending}}) {0}[Snip]),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "CountUp", each List.Count(Text.Split([LevelUp],"|"))-1),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "CountDown", each List.Count(Text.Split([LevelDown],"|")))
in #"Added Custom3"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million @horseyride. I don't know why but my Excel is crashing as soon as the hierarchy is higher than 100 rows. The actual table has 150k rows. Any workaround how to solve that challange?

Comment: Not surprised. You are calling that function 150,000x100 times. I'd be amazed if it worked. You could try a few Table.Buffer() but really nothing would help. Maybe try powerbi and its path() function per @david bacci

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery is not my forte, but I hope the following may help, though I'm sure more advanced users would be able to come up with a cleaner option:

- I started of with creating a 'Index Column' which is located in the 'General' group on the 'Add Column' tab;
- I created three lists from given table, one called 'Child', the other called 'Parent' and 'Index'. I did so by right-clicking the header, then select 'Add as New Query';
- Next I created a three custom recursive functions called 'Xlookup', 'CountUp' and 'CountDown'. The M-code for the function are:

**Xlookup**:

```
(x as text)=>
if List.PositionOf(Child, Text.AfterDelimiter(x, "|", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}))<0
then x
else @Xlookup(x & "|" & Parent{List.PositionOf(Child, Text.AfterDelimiter(x, "|", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}))})
```

**CountUp**:

```
(x as number, y as text) as number =>
if List.PositionOf(Child, y)<0
then x
else @CountUp(x + 1, Parent{List.PositionOf(Child, y)})
```

**CountDown**:

```
(x as number, y as text) as number =>
if List.ContainsAny(Parent, Text.Split(y, "|"))
then @CountDown(x + 1, List.Accumulate(Index, "", (s, c) => s & (if List.Contains(Text.Split(y, "|"), Parent{c}) then Child{c} & "|" else "")))
else x
```

- I then added a 'Custom Column' concatenating the 'Child' and 'Parent' column through a pipe-delimiter:

  [image]
- An overview of my queries (7 in total now):

  [image]
- I then simply used 'Invoke Custom Function' under the 'General' group in the 'Add Column' tab three times, one for each of my custom functions:

[image]

- A last step would be to remove the 'Custom' and 'Index' column. So the final M-Code could look like:

  ```
  let
      Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Parent", type text}, {"Child", type text}}),
      #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
      #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each [Child]&"|"&[Parent]),
      #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Level Up", each CountUp(0, [Child])),
      #"Invoked Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Level Down", each CountDown(0, [Parent])),
      #"Invoked Custom Function2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function1", "String", each Xlookup([Custom])),
      #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function2",{"Index", "Custom"})
  in
      #"Removed Columns"
  ```

[image]

As you can see I didn't quite get how you would like to count the level down. To me it seemed you'd want to check the max depth of parent-child relations.

Comment: You dont need a function for CountUp. Just Split your VLOOKUP column on | and do a List.Count()

Comment: @horseyride, that seems fair to me. I just reworked my answer to include a level down calculation (thought different to what OP seems to want to return) and decided that I'd keep the level up function too. I mean, you are right but I don't want to copy your answer in that regard.

Comment: copy away!  I didn't feel like writing what was going to be very similar to your first function and stole that. All the credit to you on that one. Acceptance should go to this answer.  And I got a different answer on the level down function, so we both could be wrong or the sample data is wrong. I assumed it was based on the Child of each row so that DD->A and then stops with count of one, while you somehow have three.  But my AA/AD differs from sample

Comment: @horseyride, thank you for the response. Let me tell you how I got to three: The parent of 'A' is found (x=1), therefor, we accumulate all childres which parent == 'A' >> 'AA|DD'. Next we find all parents that are either 'AA' or 'DD' (x=2) and accumulate their respective childres > 'ASF|AD'. The next step is find all Parents equal to 'ASF' or 'AD' (x=3) and accumulate their children 'KI'. Here is where the iteration stops since no more parents equal to 'KI' can be found. Obviously this can be my very wrong interpertation of 'Level Down'.